# How can I count to 10 while summing the numbers in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I count to 10 while summing the numbers in VBA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dim Sum as Integer
Sum = 0 

Dim I as Integer

For I = 1 to 10
    Sum = Sum + I
Next
```

**Edit**: For future reference, please refer to Microsoft's MSDN section on [Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/isv/bb190538.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

The question is labeled VB6, so:

```
Dim Sum As Integer
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
    Sum = Sum + i
Next i
```

Comment: @A: if you're really not worried about verbosity, use `theVariableImUsingToCountToTenWith` instead of `i`

Comment: I like the anal retentive verbosity advocate who only uses his initial for his first name.

Comment: @Shog9: if you're really not worried about verbosity, use 'iHaveNoIdeaWhetherThisWouldWorkAsAPossibleVariableNameInVBASoIGuessItIsWorthAShotSoIAmCreatingASuperLongVariableNameToHoldSoThatICanWriteAForLoopFromOneToTen'

Answer (score 0):

Here's an optimized way to do it. No speed difference, but it's good practice to know about.

1. Use long instead of integer since excel natively uses longs
2. Unwrap the loop at least one level

   ```
   Dim Sum As Long
   Dim i As Long

   For i = 1 to 10 Step 2
      Sum = Sum + i
      Sum = Sum + (i + 1)
   Next
   ```

I hope that helps!